# Remove non-digits from all values in a flat array

Tags: php, laravel, array-map

I have a controller in Laravel.

This is my collection:

```
$milestones = $this->getmilestones();
dump($milestones);
```

and the value is

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "["109"
  1 => "110"
  2 => "111"]"
]
```

And I tried this code based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036228/php-array-map-changes-the-first-key-to-zero-when-it-was-originally-one).
So, I have code like this

```
array_unshift($milestones, $milestones[0]);
unset($milestones[0]);
dump($milestones);
```

and the value is (index was changed)

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => "["109"
  2 => "110"
  3 => "111"]"
]
```

So, after unshifting the collections, I tried to use array_map to convert array of strings to array of integers.

```
$milestones = array_map('intval', $milestones);
dump($milestones);
```

But, I still got the same value. The first index returns 0 like this

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => 0
  2 => 110
  3 => 111
]
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to re-key the array after converting the values to ints, like: `[1 => 109, 2 => 110, 3 => 111]`?

Comment: not yet. Okay, I'll try it

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: My expected result is array of string converted to array of integer and the first index not 0. the collections value is ("109" "110" "111") and I want result (109 110 111). But in this case the first index changed to 0 like this (0 110 111)

Comment: `array_values(array_map('intval', $this->getmilestones()))` should work.

Comment: it's same, the first index value always changed into 0 :'(

Comment: You seem to have an odd set of double quotes `0 => "["109"` and `2 => "111"]"`. Is it being output as a string? Have a look here, is this what you're trying to achieve? https://repl.it/repls/HungryScholarlyReality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, finally I got the results that I wanted. I try to remove square brackets and double quote. Because milestones is collection. So my code is

```
$milestones = str_replace(array('[', ']', '"'),'',$milestones);
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: If `$milestones` is a collection and you want a zero based index array use the method `->values()` on your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
array_splice($milestone, 0, 1);
dump($milestone);
```

Comment: the result like this

array:2 [▼
  0 => "110"
  1 => "111"]"
]

109 removed. But I need all the value

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_values` this should re-index your array the way you need it:

```
$milestones = array_values($milestones);
```

If `$milestones` is a collection:

```
$milestones = $milestones->values();
```

The method `values()` will call `array_values` on your items defined in your collection instance.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php