# start $io->choice() at option 1

Tags: php, symfony

I am using $io->choice() to offer some selections in a RoboFile setup. It uses symfony's $io class.

The options that are given are starting at 0, not 1. Is it possible to offer options starting from 1 instead of 0 or maybe add a "non-selectable option" for the first item? (0 is quite far away from 1,2,3 on the keyboard).

[image: Sample Image]

- [the function in question](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/eb2972e7f7acda0f5f189d867d08074307721c14/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php#L228)
- [Robo.li's $io docs](https://robo.li/getting-started/#io)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the array key to start from 1 instead of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374202/how-to-change-the-array-key-to-start-from-1-instead-of-0)

Comment: @EternalHour it was unclear to me that the function changes a one-dimensional array into an indexed one. I think my question is more related to the io() function of Symfony. I know how to change indexes - if I know they are there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you submit to choice() needs to start at 1.

```
$choices = [];
$choices[1] = 'hdtours';
$choices[2] = 'hdtravel';
$choices[3] = 'boutiqueyachting';

$io->choice('Which installation?', $choices);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that this could be done by array keys. Opens up lots of opportunities :)